# sharedpreferences makes all the variables same

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using shared preferences to save 3 string fields. I am opening shared preferences everytime with following code in another class. I am calling this class via a function to save it.

```
mPrefs=context.getSharedPreferences(id, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

After doing this, I am saving 3 fields which are id, name and surname of a person. Save process is successful. I am holding all of those 3 variables in an object which is called person. I can get info from shared memory. When I get the info for the first person with his Id, I can do it. I am writing it out to Log. it is successful. But after getting second person info with second person's id, first person object is also second person. Shared preferences assigns all the variables to same value.

Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**

```
personGet.setId(mPrefs.getString("id", null)); 
personGet.setName(mPrefs.getString("name", null)); 
personGet.setSurname(mPrefs.getString("surname", null)); 
// This is for saving to shared preferences. 

mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(person.getId(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit(); 
editor.putString("name", person.getName()); 
editor.putString("surname", person.getSurname()); 
editor.putString("id", person.getId()); 
// This is for saving. the "id" is unique for all users –
```

Comment: show us the code on how you retrieve the persons from shared preferences.

Comment: Could you post the code which saves the values into the SharedPreferences? The most likely reason is using the same key for each field when saving a person's data, overwriting any information already saved under that key with the new value. Seeing your code would definitely help confirming that though.

Comment: `personGet.setId(mPrefs.getString("id", null));
personGet.setName(mPrefs.getString("name", null));
personGet.setSurname(mPrefs.getString("surname", null));`

This is for saving to shared preferences. 

`mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(person.getId(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
editor.putString("name", person.getName());
editor.putString("surname", person.getSurname());
editor.putString("id", person.getId());`

This is for saving. the "id" is unique for all users

Comment: try it like this:                 personGet.setId(mPrefs.getString("id", "")); personGet.setName(mPrefs.getString("name", "")); personGet.setSurname(mPrefs.getString("surname", ""));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharedPreferences is just a [Map of Key Value pairs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html)

Yes this will save your id under the key "id":

```
 editor.putString("id", "abc");
```

But doing this will override it as the key "id" is the same:

```
 editor.putString("id", "zxy");
```

So when you ask for the sharedPreference "id" you will get

```
 zxy
```

*EDIT*

Don't forget to call commit(); on your sharedpreferences

Comment: `setPersonOwner(chUtil.getPersonFromSharedMemory("1"));
Log.d("Owner", getPersonOwner().getName());
setPersonOther(chUtil.getPersonFromSharedMemory("1"));
Log.d("Other", getPersonOther().getName());
Log.d("Owner", getPersonOwner().getName());`

chUtil is getting person from shared memory. When I get user with id:1 and try to write his name to log, it is successful. After getting person from shared memory with id:2 and trying to write first person's name to log, it writes second persons name. I am always opening shared preferences with unique user id.

Comment: @user1448565 do you call sharedPrefs.commit(); before you start retrieving your second prefs.

Comment: sharedPrefs.commit() ? do you mean editor.commit or what? couldn't get it sorry :(

Comment: @user1448565 yes commit() on the edit of your shared  preferences

Comment: mPrefs.commit() ? this is my shared preferences but nothing comes like that.. It is an error when I write it

Comment: personGet.setName(mPrefs.getString("name", ""));
personGet.setSurname(mPrefs.getString("surname", ""));
mPrefs.edit().commit();
return personGet;

Doing this, but still assigning all the variables, with last info :(

Comment: It works now. I have no idea what I have really done, but it works. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

when we get data from preferences we write it like this

```
    personGet.setId(mPrefs.getString("id", ""));
```

Comment: That doesn't matter, it just means if it isn't found it returns a blank string rather than in his question it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit or save something in shared preferences, you need to call "commit()".
It will be like that,

```
mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(person.getId(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();

editor.putString("name", person.getName()).commit();